# Unexpected errors in all test files when store is imported in a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using Jest and Enzyme to test my React application. Everything works fine but when I import redux `store` in a utility file, almost all tests get failed. with this error:

```
 FAIL  app/containers/Login/LoginContainer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _redux.combineReducers) is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/index.jsx:31:2022)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/utils/httpStatusParser.js:3:40)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/utils/requestHandler.js:135:369)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/redux/modules/user.js:148:54)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/containers/Login/LoginContainer.test.js:5:13)
      at next (native)
      at next (native)
```

Here is some code:

app/index.jsx:

```
import React           from 'react'
import ReactDOM        from 'react-dom'
import { Provider }    from 'react-redux'
import thunk           from 'redux-thunk'
import createHistory   from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'

import routes          from '$CONFIG/routes'
import { authUser }    from '$REDUX/modules/user'
import { getCookie }   from '$UTILS/cookies'
import * as reducers   from '$REDUX'


const history = createHistory()
const routeMW = routerMiddleware(history)

export const store   = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router : routerReducer
  }),
  compose(applyMiddleware(routeMW, thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : (func) => func)
)

// ...rendering provider to DOM
```

app/utils/httpStatusParser:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

import { store } from '$APP/index.jsx'
import { unauthUser } from '$REDUX/modules/user'


.
.

import { store } from '$APP/index.jsx'
import { unauthUser } from '$REDUX/modules/user'
.
.
.

store.dispatch(unauthUser) // this is when http status is 4XX
```

requestHandler.js:

```
import envURLS             from '$CONFIG/envURLS'
import httpStatusParser,
{ errorTypeDetailMap }     from './httpStatusParser'
import { getCookie }       from './cookies'

...
export get() // uses httpStatusParser
export post() // uses httpStatusParser
```

user.js(Reducer)

```
import { post } from '$UTILS/requestHandler'
import { errorTypeDetailMap } from '$UTILS/httpStatusParser'
import { setCookie } from '$UTILS/cookies'

...
export unauthUser() // Action Creator
...
```

Here is one of test file code:

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

import * as userActionCreators from '$REDUX/modules/user'
import { LoginContainer, mapStateToProps } from './LoginContainer'

// Snapshot matching for Login Container
describe('>>> Login Container -- Snapshot Test', () => {
  const initialState = userActionCreators.initialState

  it('Matches the snapshot with isFetching false', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<LoginContainer {...initialState} />).toJSON()

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('Matches the snapshot when log in button is clicked', () => {
    const updatedState = {
      ...initialState,
      isFetching : true
    }

    const tree = renderer.create(<LoginContainer {...updatedState} />).toJSON()

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
// *************************************************************
```

LoginContainer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import { Login } from '$COMPONENTS'
import { getCookie }   from '$UTILS/cookies'
import * as userActionCreators from '$REDUX/modules/user'
```

The flow is:

- Container Calls Async Action Creator from a reducer
- Async Action creator makes a `get`/`post` call exposed by `requestHandler.js`
- requestHandler imports `httpStatusParser` to parse the status. If request status in 4XX, the user should be redirected to `/login`.
- httpStatusParser imports `store` from `index.jsx` to dispatch `unauthUser` action.

I couldn't figure out how to resolve this issue. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: It is highly probable that the issue is a circular dependency. Can you share the repo link (if it is publicly available)?

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda Can't share the Repo link as it's private Repo. Let me add module requests for files showed in errors.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda Added all dependencies

Comment: While I take a look at this, try deleting the node_modules folder and then re-installing dependencies

Comment: getting same error after reinstalling.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda so, there was a circular dependency: user.js > requestHandler.js(get) > httpStatusParser.js(httpStatusParser) > user.js (unauthUser) which is a circular dependency(not sure if that counts)

I moved that code to separate file, but the error still persists :/

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing the `combineReducers` function. Should be

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
```

Comment: I am importing in the same way. The problem is because of importing `unauthUser` in the `httpStatusParser`. If I comment this, everything works fine.

Comment: FWIW this is how I am importing `combineReducer`:

`import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'`